# Python Tkinter GUI execute python script error

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, face-recognition

I use the below code for gui and the error say that no module named cv2, but if run it in ide or command prompt it work. Anyone else know what's the problem i faced or any suggestion?

`os.system('python faceDetect.py')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For calling Python scripts from Python I recommend using [runpy.run_module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html#runpy.run_module) instead to avoid the overhead of spawning a new Python process:

```
import runpy
# Note that faceDetect.py must be available through PYTHON_PATH / sys.path
runpy.run_module('faceDetect', run_name='__main__')
```

Answer (score 0):

call it using `subprocess`.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('python faceDetect.py')
```